# Go program is running into a dedlock with the introduction of channels in the program

Tags: go, channel

I am new to the go channels,
I am trying to learn go channels by constructing a mock kernel and processes communication through channel. The aim of this sample program is have multiple processes (2) sending `memory` request to the kernel using a single channel. However, my program is running into deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

const (
    _ float64 = iota
    LowPrio
    MedPrio
    HghPrio
)

// Kernel type to communicate between processes and memory resources
type Kernel struct {
    reqMemCh chan chan int
}

func (k *Kernel) Init() {
    k.reqMemCh = make(chan chan int, 2)
}

// Fetch memory on process request
func (k *Kernel) GetReqMemCh() chan chan int {
    return k.reqMemCh
}

func (k *Kernel) AllocMem() {
    // loop over the items (process reply channels) received over
   // the request channel
    for pCh := range k.GetReqMemCh() {
        // rpCh := make(chan int)
        // m := <-rpCh
        // for now think 0 is the available index
        // send this as a reply to the exclusive process reply channel
        pCh <- 0  
        close(pCh)
    }
}

// Process type which requests memory
type Proc struct {
    ind     int
    prio    float64
    exeT    time.Time
    count   int
    memInd  int
    rqMemCh chan chan int
}

func (p *Proc) Init(
    ind int,
    prio float64,
    rqMemCh chan chan int,
) {
    p.ind = ind
    p.prio = prio
    p.memInd = -1
    p.rqMemCh = rqMemCh
}

func (p *Proc) GetReqMemCh() chan chan int {
    return p.rqMemCh
}

func (p *Proc) ReqMem() {
    // create the reply channel exclusive to the process
    // this channel will return the allocated memeory id/address
rpCh := make(chan int)
    // send the reply channel through the request channel
    // to get back the allocation memory id
    p.GetReqMemCh() <- rpCh
    // Below line is blocking ...
    for mi := range rpCh {
        p.memInd = mi
    }
}

func (p Proc) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(
        "Proc(%d): Memory(%d), Count(%d)",
        p.ind+1, p.memInd+1, p.count,
    )
}

func main() {

    k := &Kernel{}
    k.Init()
    go k.AllocMem()

    p := &Proc{}
    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        p.Init(i, LowPrio, k.GetReqMemCh())
        p.ReqMem()
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.(*Proc).ReqMem(...)
        main.go:65
main.main()
        main.go:86 +0x14e

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.(*Kernel).AllocMem(0x0?)
        main.go:31 +0x59
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        main.go:81 +0x98
exit status 2
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong and how can I acheive a design like

```
+--------+                                               
|        |                                    +---------+
|   P1  -\                                    |         |
|        |--\    +----------------------+     |         |
+--------+   -\  |                      |     | KERNEL  |
               --|    CHANNEL          -------|         |
              -/ |                      |     |         |
+---------+ -/   +----------------------+     |         |
|         -/                                  +---------+
|   P2   /|                                              
|         |                                              
+---------+
```

Using `go` channels.

Cheers,

DD

Comment: `for mi := range rpCh` will only exit when the [channel `rpCh` is closed](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range) "the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel until the channel is closed". `rpCh` is never closed hence the deadlock. I suspect the first step is to move `go k.AllocMem()` before your loop (but this exposes [further issues](https://go.dev/play/p/NPalaeXDbIU)). Some comments would make it easier to understand your intentions.

Comment: `close(pCh)` is the `rpCh` which do get closed. Going by your comment about the `range`   loop, I think I have to close `k.GetReqMemCh()`. However, this means none of the other processes can send their request to this channel which is not what I want. I want a single channel to be open forever and keep receiving requests and have exclusive(to clients) reply channels to send the replies back to the client. Hope it make sense.

Comment: "close(pCh) is the rpCh which do get closed." - It would if that code ever ran (you need to move the `go k.AllocMem()` above the loop; otherwise the code deadlocks before the go routine is even started). You don't have to close `k.GetReqMemCh()`, just the channel that is received via `k.GetReqMemCh()` (passing channels over channels works but can be confusing!). See the link in my original comment for the other issue - it's not clear what `AllocMem()` is supposed to do when a request is received.

Comment: What is the output you get? That's missing from the question. That should also answer the question how you know that it has a deadlock.

Comment: added the output, line numbers may be of a bit because here I added comments.

Comment: @Brits, I have already closed the received channel  in `close(pCh)`.

Comment: And with the changes you have made the latest version is [no longer deadlocked](https://go.dev/play/p/1rtojkuzgXT).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your go runtime is not able to detect the sleep function. Intentionally you have put the sleep and it makes sense but go runtime doesn’t know it. So `AllocMem` may not be finished allocating before the main exits. Hence the pattern comes that Channel is not populated with data before you are requesting and hence it is a blocked state or deadlock.

Now to fix this you can bring in some constructs that go runtime understands and realise that you want to wait till all the allocation should be done before the main exits. Hence just create `sync.WaitGroup` before `k.AllocMem()` and add 1 before the call with `defer wg.Done()`. And in place of sleep just add `wg.Wait()`. This might work.

Comment: The `sleep` is not needed at all (`p.ReqMem()` sends a request on a channel and then waits for a response, so the operation is really sequential). In any event, the program exits after the `Sleep` so you would not get a deadlock at that point (the program will just exit).